# ntopng is very slow

Tags: debian, security

I use the default ntopng version that you can obtain by `apt-get install ntopng` in debian 9.

The daemon is slow in starting, even more slow in closing and the cpu utilization is high.

There's something that I can do to improve the closing time and lower the cpu % / improving the performances ?

Also, is considered to be safe install ntopng by it's repository to get a newer and maybe optimized version or could I be more uncovered in terms of security and create a "frankendebian" ?

My machine is a 4 gb ram with a gigabit ethernet.

Comment: you can `strace` the process to find out what it's doing (and thus maybe how it's wasting so much CPU time). If you install a `deb` from a "not Debian" source then of course you have created a "frankendebian" but you can deinstall that version later and reinstall the debian version if your dependencies break or something. You need to be fluent with `dpkg`/`apt` etc. of course.

Comment: It's very slow, webpage is responding waaay to slow. Using latest version from `http://packages.ntop.org/debian/stretch/x64` .